# Run a javascript onclick event from a text content

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an onClick event that comes from a String as follows.

```
const text = `some text and <sup onClick={handleClick}>123</sup>`;
```

This text is actually coming from an external API response.

And I have a `handleClick` function as follows:

```
const handleClick = () => alert('clicked!');
```

This handleClick function is in my component. I expect the alert to occur when the sup text `123` is clicked.

The text is clickable, but when I click it, I get the error:

```
Unhandled Runtime Error
ReferenceError: handleClick is not defined

Call Stack
HTMLElement.onclick
```

But handleClick is there in the component.

I even validated it with a button that doesn't use the text. That works fine.

Why doesn't it work for the text and how could I resolve this?

Component

```
export default function Home() {

  const handleClick = () => alert('clicked!');

  const text = `some text and <sup onClick={handleClick}>123</sup>`; // assume this comes from an api.
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: text }} /> // this is the line throwing error when I click it.


      // this button shows the alert fine when clicked.
      <button
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Click me now!
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Maybe this has something to do with react's virtual dom being a different env than the window object normally? Try something like adding a one time `useEffect` that adds the function to the global scope? And is it possible to not have the inner html be jsx?

Comment: Pretty sure that `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` expects `HTML` and not JSX in which case `onClick={handleClick}` doesn't mean anything. It would need to be `onclick="handleClick()"` as you would pass to a regular HTML element.

Comment: You might look at the legacy [`createElement`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/createElement) (but asyncawaits comment re: scoping will still need to be looked into)

Comment: Thanks both. A combination worked where I do have to set the function to window and onclick="handleClick() worked. Having a look at createElement. Just checking the cleanest way to do this cos setting the function to window would need useEffect  as  window may not be available from the start. Was trying to avoid having to use useEffect.

Comment: Do you have the ability to alter the API response? What can we assume about it?

Comment: @code I have full access to alter the api as needed.

Comment: you could just have an event listener sitting on top and listen to which class of element was clicked, then fire events based on what element was clicked. Then you wouldn't need to change scope really. But there's probably a better way to do this without dangerously setting innerhtml. i.e. passing the text / content into components that are premade and have options, and you expect a set of options in response from your api.

Comment: Do you have to define the handler function on the server or is there always one handler for all click events? Do they all need to be wrapped in `<sup>`, do they vary, or does it not matter?

Comment: @asyncawait For context, receiving a very complex json response. 
Intention to search through that json response and update all sup tags to have this onclick event. This is done in backend.
Then from front end just have this handleClick function react to it on click. That's the intention. All the sup tags on click will react to same handleClick function. It essentially sets the state to open/close a modal on click.

Comment: @code Doesn't have to be on the server end. Yes one handler for these events for sup tags. They will be wrapped in <sup>. Have a look at context above.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You're getting the function itself from the api or just the element content? I can give you an example of having the listener sit on top and react to any dynamically created children even outside the react env without using `useEffect` or a global scope, however if you're trying to let react manage the state of children created, you're going to want to parse the parts of data into children that fit a component instead of trying to get a string containing jsx to render as react. You could always have state managed without react, but then it starts to have a code smell.

Comment: @asyncawait Function name comes from api. The function implementation occurs on front end. State is just to open close a modal. Thus not doing anything specific to parse and fit data to children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using altered api txt with onclick being html and not jsx, as well as adding the function to global scope using `uesEffect`

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const Home = () => {
  const handleClick = () => alert('clicked!');
  const text = `some text and <sup onClick="handleClick()">123</sup>`;
  useEffect(() => {
    window.handleClick = handleClick;
  }, []);
  return (
    <div>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: text }} />

      <button
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Click me now!
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <Home />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Here's an example without `useEffect` that would listen to the parent for which child was clicked, if you have the ability to shape used data to have a data attribute with which function is meant to be hit.

```js
const {useState, useEffect} = React;

const Home = () => {
  const handleClick1 = () => alert('clicked1!');
  const handleClick2 = () => alert('clicked2!');
  const handleClick3 = () => alert('clicked3!');
  const text1 = `1 text and <sup data-func="func1">123</sup>`;
  const text2 = `2 text and <sup data-func="func2">123</sup>`;
  const text3 = `3 text and <sup data-func="func3">123</sup>`;
  const handleAllClicks = e => {
    const func = e.target.dataset.func;
    switch (func) {
      case "func1": return handleClick1();
      case "func2": return handleClick2();
      case "func3": return handleClick3();
    }
  };
  return (
    <div onClick={handleAllClicks}>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: text1 }} />
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: text2 }} />
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: text3 }} />
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(
    document.getElementById("root")
).render(
    <Home />
);
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: ideally I would avoid dangerously set, and just have the data which decides which function to use lookup the desired function of front end and place that in a component.

Answer (score 1):

When you `dangerouslySetInnerHTMl` you are setting HTML, not React JSX. Your div will be rendered into the HTML DOM something like this:

```html
<div>
  some text and <sup onclick="{handleClick}">123</sup>
</div>
```

In essence, this is a regular HTML gross `onclick` property that's executed in the context of the window as pure JS, not React. The curly braces are still valid JS, but there is no defined property `handleClick`, so you get a reference error.

Try running the following snippet and inspect the HTML and you'll see what I mean:

```js
function Home() {
  const handleClick = () => alert('clicked!')

  const text = `some text and <sup onClick={handleClick}>123</sup>`
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: text }} />
      <button
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Click me now!
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<Home />)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

The only thing I can think of is using the React create element instead:

```js
function DataRender({ data, onClick }) {
  return React.createElement(
    "div",
    null,
    ...data.map(seg => {
      if(!seg.clickable) return seg.value
      return React.createElement(
        "sup",
        { onClick },
        seg.value
      )
    })
  )
}

function Home() {
  const handleClick = () => alert('clicked!')

  // change your API to give JSON responses or manually process
  const data = [{ value: "some text and " }, { value: "123", clickable: true }]
  
  return (
    <div>
      <DataRender data={data} onClick={handleClick} />
      <button
        onClick={handleClick}
      >
        Click me now!
      </button>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<Home />)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you are trying to access the handleClick function inside a string, which is not possible as JavaScript evaluates the string as plain text. To resolve this issue, you need to parse the string as HTML and dynamically bind the event handler to the element in the DOM. You can use a library like React-DOM-Parser to parse the string as HTML and bind the event handler to the element.